# Проблема с позиционированием всплывающей подсказки

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! С помощью данного [плагина](http://jquerylist.ru/tooltipe/tiptip.html) сделал всплывающую подсказку для своей [навигационной карты](http://ooomercury.com/plan/), в инструкции было написано, что можно применить абсолютно к любому тэгу, которому можно прописать атрибут **title** и **class**, я так и сделал, прописал для тэга **AREA**. Сама подсказка работает корректно, но вот только с позиционированием проблема, она "всплывает" не там, где надо!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть у кого-нибудь есть хоть какие-нибудь идеи. *Заранее всем спасибо!*

Comment: Если кому интересно, я нашел отличный плагин решения моей проблемы:
http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download/ - сам плагин.

Comment: Пример вкратце:

$(document).ready(function(){
$('сюда пишем класс или тег').qtip({
id: 'myTooltip',
content: {
text: 'здесь текст подсказки',
},
position: 
{                       
my: 'right center',  //Это позиционирование
at: 'bottom left',  //Это позиционирование
},
show: {
delay: 150, //Задержка
style: {
classes: 'ui-tooltip-green ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools ui-tooltip-rounded', //Дефолтные стили подсказки, можно менять на свои
width:200,     
},
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте задать для тэга <area style="position:relative" />

Напишите, сработало или нет.

Comment: Не совсем сработало, теперь подсказка появляется внизу экрана

Comment: Запихнул AREA в DIV и уже DIV`у задаю стили. РАБОТАЕТ!

Comment: Ухтыыыыы........